# How to remove extra whitespace on link transform

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to remove the extra white space. When I hover over each link, there seems to be an extra space covered by the underline after each word. I have used this CSS to format my links:

```css
.navigation_links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 20px;
}

.navigation_links a::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
    transform-origin: right;
}

.navigation_links a:hover::before {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <span class="navigation">
        <span class="navigation_links">
            <a class="menu" href="menu.html">
                Menu
            </a>

            <a class="location" href="location.html">
                Location
            </a>

            <a class="order" href="order.html">
                Order
            </a>
        </span>

        <!--Place Image Here-->

    </span>
</nav>
```

And I get this weird extra space when hovered over after each element:
[image: Hover Link Example]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by line breaks in your `a` tag, so the html interprets as a white space.

This problem can be solve by removing the line breaks:

```html
<a class="menu" href="menu.html">Menu</a>
```

But if you want to keep you html code as is, you can do a quick hack by assign your `a` tag `display: inline-flex` (or `inline-block`) to get rid of the white spaces:

```css
.navigation_links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 20px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.navigation_links a::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
    transform-origin: right;
}

.navigation_links a:hover::before {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <span class="navigation">
        <span class="navigation_links">
            <a class="menu" href="menu.html">
                Menu
            </a>

            <a class="location" href="location.html">
                Location
            </a>

            <a class="order" href="order.html">
                Order
            </a>
        </span>

        <!--Place Image Here-->

    </span>
</nav>
```